# How to create a function with benefits of overloading without actually overloading?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, function, overloading

2 objects are in this project: `Region` and `Area`.

Both objects have a method called

```
void load();
```

This is what I want to to, not sure if it's possible:

Invoke the same `Detail` function with similar implementation depending on which object called the function.

The `Detail` function will do something like this:

```
void Detail(parameter)
{
    object_name.load();
}
```

I didn't want to write 2 overloaded functions for the each object because then I would have 2 functions with nearly identical implementations.

I have tried:

```
void Detail(string land)
{
    if(land=="region")
    {
        Region land = new Region();
    }
    else if(land=="area")
    {
        Area land = new Area();
    }        

    land.load();
}
```

But this doesn't work because `land.load()` will cause an error since the function cannot determine at definition whether land will be a `Region` or an `Area` object.

Comment: Normally you want 2 overloads with same implementation, you just have one call the other.  (or n overloads, only 1 really does much work or it's staged)  Note:  The "error" is that your `land` is simply undefined in the outer scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you want an interface.

```
public interface IShape
{
    void load();
}
```

Which both `Region` and `Area` would implement:

```
public class Region : IShape
{
    public void load() { /* Region Implementation */ }
}

public class Area : IShape
{
    public void load() { /* Area Implementation */ }  
}
```

Your detail function now looks like this:

```
void Detail(IShape shape)
{
    shape.load();
}
```

Some notes:

Interfaces define a *contract* without *implementation*.  Your `Detail` function does not need to know whether it is an `Area` or a `Region` provided the class in question adheres to the contract that `IShape` defines, that is - it has a `load()` method.

**Edit**

Looking at your question more closely, it also looks like you want to implement a factory.  So let's do that also.

```
public static class ShapeFactory
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<IShape>> _shapes = new Dictionary<string, Func<IShape>>();

    static ShapeFactory()
    {
        // Register some creators:
        _shapes.Add("region", () => return new Region());
        _shapes.Add("area", () => return new Area());
    }

    public static IShape Create(string shape) 
    {
        return _shapes[shape]();
    }
}
```

This allows your detail function to be rather simple:

```
void Detail(string shape)
{
    ShapeFactory.Create(shape).load();
}
```

Error checking omitted for brevity.  So what does this do?  Well, a factory is - well - a factory.  We create a dictionary (keyed by name), and whose value is a function that returns an `IShape`..  we can now dynamically create shapes by name and call the `load` method on it.

**Edit 2**

Given your comment that you cannot change what interfaces these classes implement, there's no reason we can't still obfuscate the load method (given that they both implement it).  All we have to do is, once again utilise our interface again:

```
public interface IShapeWrapper
{
    void load();
}
```

Note that our interface is still the same.  What *is* different is the implementations:

```
public class RegionWrapper : IShapeWrapper
{
    private Region _region;
    public RegionWrapper()
    {
        _region = new Region();
    }

    public void load()
    {
        _region.load();
    }
}


public class AreaWrapper : IShapeWrapper
{
    private Area _area;
    public AreaWrapper()
    {
        _area = new Area();
    }

    public void load()
    {
        _area.load();
    }
}
```

The factory remains much the same, with the exception that it takes the wrapper classes rather than the Area/Region ones.

Comment: One problem is that I'm using these objects from a black-box .dll, so I have no way of changing the their object definition to inherit a new interface or create the factory for that matter since I see that it needs the IShape interface to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Due to the logic of my Detail function, it requires additional changes to different attributes within the 2 objects which makes it pretty hard to create an interface that satisfies both of them. I've decided to just make 2 functions with specific parameters.

I'm sure this will help people with functions that only use attributes/methods within both objects. So I marked it as answer.

Comment: @RedAces, if you want to open up a new question with more detail on the attributes/methods we could take a look at it and see if there is a neat pattern or trick we can use to make your life easier?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to make the classes share an interface, e.g.

```
public interface ILoad { void Load(); }
public class Area : ILoad { }
public class Region : ILoad { }

void Detail(ILoad land)
{
    land.Load();
}
```

Or maybe use `dynamic`, e.g.

```
void Detail(string landStr)
{
    dynamic land;
    if (landStr == "region")
    {
        land = new Region();
    }
    else
    {
        land = new Area();
    }        

    land.load();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of addressing this. A simple way would be giving both `Area` and `Region` classes an `ILoadable` interface to implement, like this:

```
interface ILoadable {
    void load();
}
class Area : ILoadable {
    public void load() {...}
}
class Region : ILoadable {
    public void load() {...}
}
```

Now you can change your `Detail` method as follows:

```
void Detail(string land) {
    ILoadable loadable;
    if(land=="region") {
        loadable = new Region();
    } else if(land=="area") {
        loadable = new Area();
    } else {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(land);
    }
    loadable.load();
}
```

If you would like to make `Detail` a generic function, you can get rid of the `string land` parameter, and pass the class directly:

```
void Detail<T>() where T : ILoadable, new() {
    new T().load();
}
```

You can call this function like this:

```
Detail<Region>();
Detail<Area>();
```

Comment: +1 from me - don't you just hate the random downvoters with nothing better to do?

Comment: @Moo-Juice might have been the double post.  Note: if there are "several solutions" why did everyone come up with interface unanimously?  (Not that I've a better)

Comment: @ebyrob because it's a logical conclusion :)  And there was no double post, dasnlinkenlight deleted the other post because it was downvoted for no discernible reason.

Comment: As an aside, dasblinkenlight - after reading a post from /r/talesfromtechsupport on reddit last night - I finally understand your username.  Well played, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Going the interface way is quite a possibility, or creating a full fledged Factory also, but it might be overkill depending on your need.

If you expect to have a lot more functions like `load()`, do it the way other have said, but if not, or if you cannot change what class they inherit like you stated, here is another way of doing it simply and quickly using `dynamics`:

```
void Detail(string land)
{
    dynamic land = null;

    if (land == "region")
    {
        land = new Region();
    }
    else if (land == "area")
    {
        land = new Area();
    }
    else
    {
        // Not what we expected
        throw new ArgumentException("land: " + land);
    }       

    try
    {
        land.load();
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException ex)
    {
        // .load() does not exist
    }
}
```